# Adjust padding inside matplotlib annotation box

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the `annotate` method on an `Axes` object to add an arrow with text to a plot.  For example:

```
ax.annotate('hello world,
            xy=(1, 1),
            xycoords='data',
            textcoords='data',
            fontsize=12,
            backgroundcolor='w',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc3")
```

This works well but I want to decrease the padding on the inside of the annotation box.  Essentially, I want to make the box 'squeeze' tighter around the text.  Is there any way to do this via the `arrowprops` or `bbox_props` kwargs?

I'm looking for something like `borderpad` that's available on legends, similar to what's discussed [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20049202/1108031).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to switch to a slightly different way of specifying the box.  The "basic" box doesn't support it, so you need to have `annotate` make a `FancyBboxPatch` associated with the text object.  (The same syntax for a "fancy" box would work text placed with `ax.text` as well, for what it's worth.)

---

Also, before we go much farther, there are a couple of rather thorny bugs that affect this in the current version of matplotlib (1.4.3).  (e.g. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4139  and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4140)

If you're seeing things like this:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

You might consider downgrading to matplotlib 1.4.2 until the issue is fixed.

---

Let's take your example as a starting point. I've changed the background color to red and put it in the center of the figure to make it a touch easier to see.  I'm also going to leave off the arrow (avoiding the bug above) and just use `ax.text` instead of `annotate`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'hello world',
            fontsize=12,
            backgroundcolor='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

To be able to change the padding, you'll need to use the `bbox` kwarg to `text` (or `annotate`). This makes the text use a `FancyBboxPatch`, which supports padding (along with several other things).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'hello world', fontsize=12,
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', fc='red', ec='none'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

The default padding is `pad=0.3`.  (If I recall correctly, the units are fractions of the height/width of the text's extent.) If you'd like to increase it, use `boxstyle='square,pad=<something_larger>'`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'hello world', fontsize=12,
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square,pad=1', fc='red', ec='none'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or you can decrease it by putting in `0` or a negative number to shrink it farther:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'hello world', fontsize=12,
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square,pad=-0.3', fc='red', ec='none'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description.  I ended up using `annotate` but calling `set_bbox` with the `pad` arguments you suggested and worked like a charm.