# Padding text in matplotlib.text

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am looking for a reasonable way to pad text for matplotlib.text. I saw the bbox has a nice pad option but it does only pad the box and does not move the text. Also strangely enough `bbox={'linestyle':'None'}` does not remove the box line, however, other linestyles are working as expected. Any suggestions?

Use case is relative positioning of text on the plotting area. Using coordinates (1,0.5) puts it too close to the plotting boundary line to look good, and somehow I am reluctant to do (0.99,0.5). That would require change if someone changes fontsize etc.

Comment: `linestyle` [cannot be 'None'](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_linestyle), if you don't want a border, you should set `linewidth=0`

Comment: Also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119092/adjust-padding-inside-matplotlib-annotation-box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [`annotate()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate), which is more flexible than `text`. You can easily offset the text from the anchor point by a certain number of points (or pixels).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.annotate('test', xy=(1,0.5), xytext=(-5,0), xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', ha='right')
```

[image]